# How do I open the "front camera" on the Android platform?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

More generally, if a device has more than one embedded camera,
is there a way to initialize one of them in particular?

I didn't find it in Android reference documentation:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html

Samsung SHW-M100S has two cameras. If there is no reference to use two cameras, any idea how Samsung did...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Front Facing Camera on Samsung Galaxy S](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241292/how-to-use-front-facing-camera-on-samsung-galaxy-s)

Answer (score 114):

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}
```

Add the following permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

**Note:** This feature is available in Gingerbread(2.3) and Up Android Version.

Comment: Is it possible to use this somehow with the `Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` technique to open the existing camera app?

Comment: @loeschg `Intent` handles camera action in its own way. This technique is used when you are using `SurfaceView` to exploit camera functionality.

Comment: that's what I figured. Thanks!

Comment: Very cool post. Took me a while to figure out that camera facing is not neccessarily the same than the camera index. For example my tablet has only one camera (index: 0) but facing front (facing index: 1). Therefore using the simple code like Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) is nonesense.

Comment: @Matthias Agree with you mate. As we have different OEMs, our programming technique gets changed as per our needs. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: not working with pie or oreo updated version of android

Answer (score 14):

All older answers' methods are deprecated by Google (supposedly because of troubles like this), since API 21 you need to [use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) the Camera 2 API:

> This class was deprecated in API level 21. We recommend using the new
>   android.hardware.camera2 API for new applications.

In [the newer API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html) you have **almost complete power** over the Android device camera and documentation explicitly advice to

```
String[] getCameraIdList()
```

and then use obtained CameraId to open the camera:

```
void openCamera(String cameraId, CameraDevice.StateCallback callback, Handler handler)
```

**99% of the frontal cameras have id = "1", and the back camera id = "0"**
according to this:

> Non-removable cameras use integers starting at 0 for their
>   identifiers, while removable cameras have a unique identifier for each
>   individual device, even if they are the same model.

**However**, this means if device situation is rare like just 1-frontal -camera tablet you need to count how many **embedded** cameras you have, and place the order of the camera by its importance ("0"). So CAMERA_FACING_FRONT == 1 CAMERA_FACING_BACK == 0, which implies that the back camera is more **important** than frontal.

I don't know about a **uniform** method to identify the frontal camera on all Android devices. Simply said, the Android OS inside the device can't really find out which camera is exactly where for some reasons: maybe the only camera hardcoded id is an integer representing its importance or maybe on some devices whichever side you turn will be .. "back".

**Documentation**: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

**Explicit Examples**: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

---

**For the older API** (it is not recommended, because it will not work on modern phones newer Android version and transfer is a pain-in-the-arse). Just use the same *Integer* CameraID  (1) to open frontal camera like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767832/5059838):

```
cam = Camera.open(1);
```

---

If you trust **[OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android)** to do the camera part:

Inside

```
    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    ../>
```

use the following for the frontal camera:

```
        opencv:camera_id="1"
```

Answer (score 10):

As of Android 2.1, Android only supports a single camera in its SDK. It is likely that this will be added in a future Android release.

Comment: this statment is valid for Android 2.2 aswell?

Comment: @ozmank: Yes, multiple-camera support was not added until Android 2.3.

Answer (score 6):

To open the **back** camera:-

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA)
```

To open the **front** camera:-

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
when {
     Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
         cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)  // Tested on API 24 Android version 7.0(Samsung S6)
     }
     Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
         cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) // Tested on API 27 Android version 8.0(Nexus 6P)
         cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)
     }
     else -> cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1)  // Tested API 21 Android version 5.0.1(Samsung S4)
}
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA)
```

I could not make it work for API 28 and above. Also, opening the front camera directly is not possible in some devices(depends on the manufacturer).

Comment: Did you get any solution to this for API 28 and above?

Comment: for back camera solution is not working

Answer (score 4):

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.set("camera-id",2);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good working on Galaxy S Important  "camera-id" not "camera_id"

Comment: Never assume 90 degrees will get you the correct rotation for portrait. It's different on many devices.

Answer (score 4):

For API 21 (5.0) and later you can use the [CameraManager API's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html)

```
try {
    String desiredCameraId = null;
    for(String cameraId : mCameraIDsList) {
        CameraCharacteristics chars =  mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        List<CameraCharacteristics.Key<?>> keys = chars.getKeys();
        try {
            if(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT == chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)) {
               // This is the one we want.
               desiredCameraId = cameraId;
               break;
            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // This key not implemented, which is a bit of a pain. Either guess - assume the first one
            // is rear, second one is front, or give up.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the release of [Android 2.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Gingerbread) (Gingerbread), you can now use the `android.hardware.Camera` class to get the number of cameras, information about a specific camera, and get a reference to a specific `Camera`. Check out the new `Camera` APIs [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/9/changes/android.hardware.Camera.html).

Answer (score 1):

**build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
    }
```

**Set View**

```
CameraSourcePreview mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);

GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay) findViewById(R.id.faceOverlay);

CameraSource mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
                            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
                            .build();

           mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Camera camera;   
if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2) {

    //if you want to open front facing camera use this line   
    camera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

    //if you want to use the back facing camera
    camera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);                
}

try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay("your surface holder here");
    camera.startPreview();      
} catch (Exception e) {  
    camera.release();
}
```

/* This is not the proper way, this is a solution for older devices that run Android 4.0 or older. This can be used for testing purposes, but not recommended for main development. This solution can be considered as a temporary solution only. But this solution has helped many so I don't intend to delete this answer*/

Comment: I don't think it's documented usage. open(int id) accepts the id, not camera position

Comment: please remove this misleading answer

Comment: @AlexCohn Can you please explain why this answer should be removed. It seems like many of them are fine with the answer.

Comment: @AmalanDhananjayan: see for example the comment by [@Matthias](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1739297/matthias) [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4767832/192373): _…Took me a while to figure out that camera facing is not neccessarily the same than the camera index. For example my tablet has only one camera (index: 0) but facing front (facing index: 1). Therefore using the simple code like Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) is nonesense._

Comment: **This is balderdash. Don't even attempt to use this.**

Comment: This is horrific. Do not EVER do this. This answer should be banned. Camera.open() accepts a camera id, not the ordinal value of the camera facing! This fails across a significant minority of devices and only works through sheer dumb luck.

Comment: @AlexCohn Please stop defacing this answer and adding your flair to it. The objections in the comments are sufficient, posts shouldn't be edited to add meta information

Comment: @Clive: this approach was supported by Community: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311430/192373

Comment: I don't believe that's policy, just a somewhat popular opinion on that day. Flagged for mod to make the decision, easier that way @AlexCohn. If you want to rollback my rollback in lieu of that please do

Comment: @Clive, my experience getting mod attention has never been very successful. I will be glad if it works now.

Comment: @Clive, thanks, we did get mod attention. Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I found this works nicely.

```
fun frontCamera(context: Context): Int {
    val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    return cameraManager.cameraIdList
        .find { id ->
            cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id)[LENS_FACING] == LENS_FACING_FRONT
        }?.toInt() ?: 0
}
```