# Android: Acessing front facing camera for Android 2.3

Tags: android, camera, android-sdk-2.3

There really seems to be no information on how to acess the front facing camera on android phones (gingerbread).

Could someone please point me to a page or post that explains how it's done?

Thanks!

Comment: And oh yeah someone with higher rep should really add a front facing tag since I probably wont be the only one asking about this in the months to come ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example on how to access different cameras and switch between them: [CameraPreview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html)

The link is not accessible right now, Google has moved the Sample Project.

Please import a Sample Project and find it at:

ApiDemos/com.example.android.apis.graphics/CameraPreview.java

Answer (score 2):

Mat be this might help you [How to use Front Facing Camera on Samsung Galaxy S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241292/how-to-use-front-facing-camera-on-samsung-galaxy-s)

As for 2.3 [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) you can try this method passing the camera ID

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but that is a Galaxy S specific sollution before Gingerbread was released.