# Front-facing camera on LG Optimus 2X Speed

Tags: android, camera, android-2.2-froyo

I've gotten the [front-facing camera to work on a Samsung Galaxy S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241292/how-to-use-front-facing-camera-on-samsung-galaxy-s), but the following technique doesn't work on an LG Optimus 2X Speed:

```
Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.set("camera-id", 2);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

The above code still only displays video from the back-facing camera. The Camera app supports switching cameras, and it even comes bundled with a "Mirror" app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revealed all the parameters using

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
Log.d("camera", parameters.flatten());
```

Which revealed a field called `camera-sensor`. Surely enough, I got it working by specifying

```
parameters.set("camera-sensor", 1);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: I got briefly excited when I read this - maybe this is a way to switch cameras that's faster than release/open!

But as your experience suggests, the string parameters are device-dependent. On a Galaxy Nexus, for example, `flatten()` shows that the only `camera-` parameter is `camera-name`.

Comment: I believe that despite the parameter you still need release and open the camera to switch.