# Switching between android phone's front and back cameras

Tags: android, android-camera

I wanted to use both the cameras simultaneously, but it is not supported as of now. The next approach was to switch the cameras as fast as possible.
I found that a switching delay of 400 ms was visible, but a delay of 200 ms was not detected by the eyes.

I want to know what is the lowest switching time that can be reached.

If the frame rate is 30 fps ( 33.33 ms per frame) , then can it be safely said that the lowest switching time cannot be less than 33.33 ms?

Has anyone tried anything similar? Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried switching between them?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am unable to detect the change below a range. I want to know what is the lowest bound that can be achieved?

Comment: Have look on this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599454/switch-back-front-camera-on-fly

Answer (score 0):

Switching is very easy. All you need is to launch the camera application, hit the switch gear icon and you are done. I stumbled it [here](http://www.thekonsulthub.com/how-tos/how-to-switch-cameras-in-android-smartphones-back-front/)

Comment: Please provide more information from the link in your answer.