# Switching between front and back camera

Tags: android

I am trying to create a custom camera app in which I need to switch between the front and back facing camera. So is it mandatory to create new camera instance every time for the type of `camera-id` to make it work? I have tried setting in `camera-id` to camera properties but it does not seem to work. Is there any other way to do this without re-instantiating the camera instance?

Comment: Look at the code in the link posted in the answer for verification, switching id will work

Comment: hi have a look at this. if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
    mCamera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
   } else {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the activity and change the camera id to 2 for switching to back camera and 1 for front i guess. Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599454/switch-back-front-camera-on-fly)

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo_camera_main);
    prepareActivity(); 
 }

 private void prepareActivity() {
    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.photo_camera_surface_view);
    turnButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.turn_button);
    turnButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(turnButton)) {
       if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1 && camId < Camera.getNumberOfCameras() - 1){
          startCamera(camId + 1);
    } else {
        startCamera(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer should be in comment.