# Camera for photo and video in same activity

Tags: android, camera

In my app, I've to implement camera for photo and video in same activity like Instagram. I've implemented camera for photo and video in different activity.
I would like to switch camera mode form photo to video and vice versa on swipe gesture like Instagram has, but I don't know how to switch camera from photo mode to video mode and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

[Android: Switch camera when button clicked See this answer in satckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765527/android-switch-camera-when-button-clicked)

this example demonstrating switching camera when clicking button, so you can use hand gesture logic instead of this

Answer (score 0):

according to instagram camera they are using viewpager wih 3 fragments(pages) and implementing every fragment with its SurfaceView (camera)

this link may helps
https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment