# How to add more work for 1 hit of "take image" button for camera app?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-camera

I'm trying to build a camera app on Android using Xamarin. What I am trying to do is when user hits the "**take image**" button, camera will automatically switch the back camera to front camera and capture the image, which means the "**take image**" button will do 2 things: switch camera and capture image at the same time.

I am new to Xamarin and developing Android app. I've searched for many tutorials to build camera app, but they seem to be simple and I do not see any override function when user hit the "**take image**" button. Here my code in Main activity (just to build the simple camera app):

```
ImageView imageView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var btnCamera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
        imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);

        btnCamera.Click += BtnCamera_Click;

    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    // When user tap on the button, open camra app
    private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Any idea would help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

This method uses the system's camera app, you cannot change the the front/ back camera here using this method.

You can read this tutorial: [Display a stream from the camera](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/textureview/display_a_stream_from_the_camera/), it shows how to use [Android.Hardware.Camera](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Hardware.Camera/) to build your own camera app.

To add a `Button` to the view so users can take photo, you may create your camera preview view for example like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextureView
      android:id="@+id/textureView"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/takephotoBtn"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="take photo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can change the Camera's front/ back camera by [Android.Hardware.Camera.Open Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.Camera.Open/p/System.Int32/).

Please refer to this thread on SO: [Android: Switch camera when button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765527/android-switch-camera-when-button-clicked)
. The code for Xamarin Android is likely the same as it is in Java.

> which means the "take image" button will do 2 things: switch camera and capture image at the same time.

By the way, I don't think it's a good idea, makes your app wired. Why you want to do this.