# How to enable front camera instead of rear camera for android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm using an old phone it's rear camera is damaged so I want to set my default camera as my front camera. Is it possible to do that everytime when I open camera app it open front camera always?

Comment: If you have root permission, try hooking the camera related methods.

Comment: 1. Root root your phone. 2.Install xposed framework. 3. Look for camera.open() method in android source code. 4. Hook that method so that the method opens camera1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Camera mCamera;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   mCamera= Camera.open(1);
}
```

Note:

0 for CAMERA_FACING_BACK

1 for CAMERA_FACING_FRONT

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
Camera.open(android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);//avoid passing hardcode values
```

Answer (score 0):

This might helpful. Source URL : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117023/5199061)

```
Button otherCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OtherCamera);

otherCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (inPreview) {
    camera.stopPreview();
}
//NB: if you don't release the current camera before switching, you app will crash
camera.release();

//swap the id of the camera to be used
if(currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
}
else {
    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
}
camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);

try {

    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
camera.startPreview();
}
```