# how to change cmera_facing to front?

Tags: android, android-camera

I create an app for take picture But it take picture fron back camera ! How I can change it for take from front camera ?
and the other problem that , It work on some device But not work on other device ?!?!

my code :

```
package com.example.user.camera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.PublicKey;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Camera camera;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public   void  onClickBtn(View v){

    if (camera == null) {
        camera  = Camera.open();
    }
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    SurfaceView mview = new SurfaceView(getBaseContext());
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(mview.getHolder());
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
        OutputStream imageFileOS;

        try {

            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
            imageFileOS.write(data);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you mean front camera?

Comment: Also you can check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599454/switch-back-front-camera-on-fly?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @JoanColmenero yes .

Comment: Then check the link of my first comment, and tell me if it was helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

have a look. This might be of some help : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29