# How to display picture in imageview photo taken by camera in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to display picture in imageview  photo taken by using front  camera in android can anybody provide code

Thanks

Comment: Same questions answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Answer (score 4):

here is the code try it

here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linear">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn" android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Click" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the activity code

```
Button btn;
int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 0;
ImageView imgView;

imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_preview);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setCompoundDrawables(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon), null, null);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                    }
      });
```

here is the onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
    case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
           Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to take photo using front camera

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform

Comment: Could you please change your " case 0: " to " case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST: "

Answer (score 2):

or study the API Demos from android [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html%22),

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public class TakingImage extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choosing_photo);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_select);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

activity_choosing_photo.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/flower"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_select"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"/>
```