# Setting photo taken using camera as thumbnai in an imageview

Tags: android

I use the following snippet(from SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994559/how-to-display-picture-in-imageview-photo-taken-by-camera-in-android)) to display photo taken using camera as a thumbnail, in an imagevew. But the thumbnail of the picture does not show up and remain blank. What can be the reason?

```
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if(extras.get("data") != null){
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
   // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imgViewPreview.getWidth();
    int targetH = imgViewPreview.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, targetW, targetH, true);
    imgViewPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgViewPreview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

will cause no actual Bitmap to be returned. It is intended to read information about the bitmap (such as width/height) without actually loading everything into memory at this time.

--> [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds)

i recommended checking out this link to the official Android SDK documentation about displaying bitmaps:
[Link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here lies your problem...

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, targetW, targetH, true);
```

Here, you are passing **picture** instead of passing **imageBitmap** which is your taken picture. So, you correct code will be...

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, targetW, targetH, true);
```

Comment: thankyou for the help, but sorry..it was my mistake while posting the question. The createScaledBitmap was in another method to which i was passing imageBitmap and it was taken in that method as picture. Please see my edit now

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I'm pointing for the problem. Please, read my answer carefully.