# capture photo from both front and back camera simultaneously

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I would like to develop an Android application which has the technique of capturing a photo from camera(both front and back) at simultaneously.I searched over internet but unfortunately I couldn't find any better solution.

**note** for example if I capture the photo from back camera,once it captured from back means then it  has to start front camera automatically for capture a photo.

Comment: Simultaneously means at the at same time. You probably mean, take picture by back camera, and then IMMEDIATELY switch to front camera and take another picture by front camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to approach this problem step by step.

1. First build functionality to take picture by back camera.
2. Once you have done that, then build functionality to take picture by front camera (most of the code will be the same, just setting the back/font camera will be different.
3. Once you have these two options built, separately, then you can combine the two by making it a three-step process: 1) take picture by back camera 2) switch the camera to front 3) take picture by front camera.

Again, as mentioned, taking picture by back and front cameras are not different, it only involves switching the cameras.

**Edited after seeing new comment:**

If you are using the built-in camera, that is using intents, then this task is not going to be an **automatic** and **immediate** thing. I thought you were building custom camera, where you can do all this by code (without intents and built-in camera). But anyways, you can still do it.

So now, the process will be:

1. Use intent to go to Camera.
2. Take a picture (which is by default back camera). Do whatever you
   want to do with this picture, save, process, etc.
3. Use another intent to go to Camera again. This time, add an extra to your intent to so    the camera defaults to front camera `intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);`
4. Take picture again.

Refer to this thread for how to launch front camera with intent:
[How to launch front camera with intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686203/how-to-launch-front-camera-with-intent)

Comment: ,I have done capture a image from back `camera` using `new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`so if you provide any example code for capturing a image from front camera,then I will implement it in my  project.

Comment: It is working good.after added `intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);` this code for front camera.when I tried to capture image from default(back camera) it always opened the front camera.after added `intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 0);` this code for back camera,both working fine.