# Capture image from both front and back camera automatically

Tags: android, android-camera

I would like to capture image from back camera `automatically`(camera has to capture a image automatically without pressing the capture button after wait for 1 sec),when I click button in my android project.After this capture, `front camera` has to start and like to capture image automatically as like back camera.I was searched over internet but didn't get any better solution for implementing this technique in my project.So anyone please help me to achieve this technique.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419940/using-both-front-and-back-cameras-simultaneously-android?rq=1

Comment: that is for capturing a video.not for image capture.

Comment: Image or video doesn't matter here, I guess your hardware have to support this feature. You have to release the connected camera object to be accessed by another. `unlock() / open()` gives you only one camera at a time.

Comment: I won't use both camera at the same time.once i take image from backcamera and then i would like to open front camera for capture.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785236/capture-photo-from-both-front-and-back-camera-simultaneously/23788095?noredirect=1

Comment: @ Nazar Merza I referred this link,here they are using camera App for capturing a image.my question is capturing a image automatically from camera app  without clicking capture button is possible?