# I want to capture picture but not go to camera phone itself but in my own apps. Like taking selfie to set profile picture

Tags: java, android-studio-2.3

I want to capture picture but go to camera phone itself but in my own apps. Like taking selfie to set profile picture

Im Using Android studio java.

I'd look everywhere but nothing to find. Or it's just I don't know what's is called this want I want to create.

[Just like this but in front camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqOM6.jpg)

Comment: Take the [tour] read [ask] and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It is called [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax)

Answer (score 0):

I found two answers that can help you:

- [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617442/android-take-photo-using-android-front-camera) has some code about taking pictures with the front camera.
- And [the correct answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785236/capture-photo-from-both-front-and-back-camera-simultaneously) helps about geting the photo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).