# How to switch Android back camera to front camera?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open “front camera” on android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)

The default setting of camera is back.
I have added one button.
When users click on it, it will change to front camera.
What steps should I implement?
Since the back camera is previewing, should I stop the preview first and camera = null and then change to front camera??
I feel confused about it.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I want to switch from back to front. Not directly use the front camera.

Comment: If you have read some of the answers on the page, you would have seen a link pointing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform/4767832#4767832
Which solves your problem.