# How to get back camera info in android 1.6 to 2.2?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

in Android 2.3 (API 9), google introduced CameraInfo to check if the given camera is the back camera or the front camera in a phone with two cameras: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html

With this example you can get info from FRONT camera: [How do I open the "front camera" on the Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform) and it's the same for BACK camera.

OK, but the problem is that i need to get info from BACK camera in a phone with android 2.2. The phone haves two cameras, front and back, and when i'm trying to get info of the camera, it returns the info of the FRONT CAMERA. I used this code:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 8){
            Camera cam = Camera.open();
            s +="<b><u>Main Camera:</u></b><br><br>";
            s += "<b>Megapixels: </b>"+getCameraMegapixels(cam) +" megapixels"; 
            s += getCamExtraInfo(cam);
            cam.release();
    }
```

I want to get the info from the main camera (the back camera), but that code gives me info from the front camera.... I'm sure there is a way to get the info from the back camera on Android 2.2 and lower devices.

Someone knows it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any Android devices running Android 2.2 with dual cameras did so beyond the Android SDK. Please contact the device manufacturer to learn how to work with their different cameras, assuming that it is possible on their device.