# Live video streaming (Recording & uploading) with Http in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

In my application I need to record a video from the device and simultaneously post it to server(for every 5 seconds). For this I am using Http service (I don't want use RTSP here). I am able to record and simultaneously post it.

But the file at server end is not able to play (even in VLC also). The size of the both files are same in bytes (server file and device file). For testing purpose to find out the problem is with server or my end, I have commented the server posting code and written data to another file in sdcard (simultaneously while recording for every 5 seconds) but that file also same size and not able to play in device or VLC.

```
package com.techgene.instantrecorder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.techgene.instantrecorder.utility.Util;

public class SafeVideoRecorder extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    public static final String EXTRA_USE_FRONT_FACING_CAMERA ="frontcamera";
    private static final String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/InstantRecorder";

    private static final int DUAL_MODE = 1;
    private static final int MONO_MODE = 2;
    private int currentMode;

    private static final String TAG = "VideoRecorder";

    public static Boolean mRecording = false;
    private Boolean mUseFrontFacingCamera = false, isFromCall = false;
    private VideoView mVideoView = null;
    private MediaRecorder mVideoRecorder = null;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private String uniqueOutFile;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private Button btnStop, btnStartRecord, btnDual, btnMono;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_recorder);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        mVideoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                try
                {
                    stopRecording();

                    if(progress != null && progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();

                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(SafeVideoRecorder.this, "", "Uploading...");

                    new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
//                          Util util = new Util();
//                          final int respCode = util.upLoad2Server(uniqueOutFile);
//                          
//                          if(currentMode == MONO_MODE)
//                          {
//                              File file = new File(uniqueOutFile);
//                              if(file.exists())
//                                  file.delete();
//                          }

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    if(progress != null && progress.isShowing())
                                        progress.dismiss();

//                                  if(respCode == 200)
//                                  {
//                                      Toast.makeText(SafeVideoRecorder.this, "Successfully uploaded to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                  }
//                                  else
//                                  {
//                                      Toast.makeText(SafeVideoRecorder.this, "Unable to upload server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                  }

                                    try {
                                        configureCameraRecorder(mVideoView.getHolder());
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    btnStartRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    btnDual.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    btnMono.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnStartRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartRecord);
        btnStartRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                btnDual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnMono.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnStartRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                startRecord();
            }
        });

        btnDual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDual);
        btnDual.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                currentMode = DUAL_MODE;
                isFromCall = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+"9703033575"));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1010);

                btnDual.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMono.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnStartRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        btnMono = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMono);
        btnMono.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                currentMode = MONO_MODE;

                btnDual.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMono.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnStartRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        //mUseFrontFacingCamera = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(EXTRA_USE_FRONT_FACING_CAMERA, false);

        if(mUseFrontFacingCamera)
        {
            // If caller wants to use front facing camera, then make sure the device has one...
            // Hard coded to only open front facing camera on Xoom (model MZ604)
            // For more universal solution try: 
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform
            String deviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
            if (deviceModel.contains("MZ604"))
            {
                mUseFrontFacingCamera = true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The App isn't designed to use this Android's front facing camera.\n " +
                                                        "The device model is : " + deviceModel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mUseFrontFacingCamera = false;
            }
        }

        final SurfaceHolder holder = mVideoView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated()");

        try
        {
            if(!isFromCall)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "configureCameraRecorder");

                configureCameraRecorder(holder);

                startRecord();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "configureCamera ONLY");

                if (mCamera != null) 
                {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }

                if (mUseFrontFacingCamera) 
                {
                    //hard coded assuming 1 is the front facing camera
                    mCamera = Camera.open(1);
                }
                else 
                {
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                }

                // Camera setup is based on the API Camera Preview demo
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                mCamera.unlock();

                mVideoRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
                mVideoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File(ROOT_DIR);

            if(!file.exists())
                file.mkdir();

            uniqueOutFile = ROOT_DIR + "/IR_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

            File outFile = new File(uniqueOutFile);
            if (outFile.exists()) 
            {
                outFile.delete();
            }

            if(mVideoRecorder != null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Recording started");

                mVideoRecorder.setOutputFile(uniqueOutFile);
                mVideoRecorder.prepare();
                mVideoRecorder.start();
                mRecording = true;

                new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Util util = new Util();
                        final int respCode = util.upLoad2Server(uniqueOutFile);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Width x Height = " + width + "x" + height);
    }

    private void stopRecording() throws Exception 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "stopRecording()");

        mRecording = false;
        if (mVideoRecorder != null) 
        {
            mVideoRecorder.stop();
            mVideoRecorder.release();
            mVideoRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mCamera != null) 
        {
            mCamera.reconnect();
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        try
        {
            stopRecording();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void configureCameraRecorder(SurfaceHolder holder) throws Exception 
    {
        if (mVideoRecorder != null)
        {
            mVideoRecorder.stop();
            mVideoRecorder.release();
            mVideoRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mCamera != null) 
        {
            mCamera.reconnect();
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        try 
        {
            if (mUseFrontFacingCamera) 
            {
                //hard coded assuming 1 is the front facing camera
                mCamera = Camera.open(1);
            }
            else 
            {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
            }

            // Camera setup is based on the API Camera Preview demo
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.unlock();

            mVideoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mVideoRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
            mVideoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mVideoRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mVideoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);// THREE_GPP

            mVideoRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);// YouTube recommended size: 320x240, OpenGazer eye tracker: 640x480 YouTube HD: 1280x720
            mVideoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20); //might be auto-determined due to lighting
            mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);// 3 megapixel, or the max of the camera
            mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);// MPEG_4_SP

            int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            // Gingerbread and up can have wide band ie 16,000 hz recordings 
            // (Okay quality for human voice)
            if (sdk >= 10) 
            {
                mVideoRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
                mVideoRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
            } 
            else
            {
                // Other devices only have narrow band, ie 8,000 hz 
                // (Same quality as a phone call, not really good quality for any purpose. 
                // For human voice 8,000 hz means /f/ and /th/ are indistinguishable)
                mVideoRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            }

//            mVideoRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000); // limit to 30 seconds
            mVideoRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) 
                {
                    if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED reached");
                            stopRecording();

                            if(progress != null && progress.isShowing())
                                progress.dismiss();

                            progress = ProgressDialog.show(SafeVideoRecorder.this, "", "Uploading...");

                            new Thread(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    Util util = new Util();
                                    final int respCode = util.upLoad2Server(uniqueOutFile);

                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() 
                                        {
                                            if(progress != null && progress.isShowing())
                                                progress.dismiss();

                                            if(respCode == 200)
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(SafeVideoRecorder.this, "Successfully uploaded to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(SafeVideoRecorder.this, "Unable to upload server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mVideoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();

        if (mCamera != null) 
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult()");

//      if(requestCode == 1010 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
//      {
//          
//      }

        isFromCall = true;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.techgene.instantrecorder.utility;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

import com.techgene.instantrecorder.Appconstants;
import com.techgene.instantrecorder.SafeVideoRecorder;
import com.techgene.instantrecorder.VideoRecorder;

public class Util 
{
    public int upLoad2Server(String sourceFileUri) 
    {
        int serverResponseCode = 0;
    //  String upLoadServerUri = "http://113.193.181.52:90/test/videos/add-video1.php";

        String upLoadServerUri = "http://113.193.181.52:90/test/videos/add-video1.php?name=sample&description=Sample video&lat="
                        + Appconstants.DEVICE_LAT
                        + "&lng="
                        + Appconstants.DEVICE_LANG;

        upLoadServerUri = upLoadServerUri.replace(" ", "%20");

        Log.e("Util", "Url: "+upLoadServerUri);

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        int bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile())
        {
            Log.e("Util", "Source File Does not exist");
            return 0;
        }

        try 
        { 
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
//          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;");
//          conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
//          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/hi.mp4");

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

//          dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+fileName);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

            buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];

            while (SafeVideoRecorder.mRecording || (!SafeVideoRecorder.mRecording && bytesAvailable > 0))
            {
                Log.e("Util", "available : " + bytesAvailable);

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

                fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                dos.flush();

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

                while (bytesAvailable <= 0 && SafeVideoRecorder.mRecording) 
                {
                    Log.e("Util", "NOT available : " + bytesAvailable);

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                }
            }

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("Util", "Upload file to server, HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            fileInputStream.close();

            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // this block will give the response of upload link
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.i("Util", "RES Message: " + line);
            }

            rd.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ioex) 
        {
            Log.e("Util", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }

        return serverResponseCode; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, was this solved? If so, how did you do it eventually?

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?