# capture photo using front camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-capture

I am following this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html#tutorial_cameraapi

only I changed **cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();** line to **cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();**

and write the method like this:

```
  private int findBackFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the back facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "back Camera found");
        cameraId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return cameraId;
  }
```

And I modify this line **camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));**

to

```
try {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.d("error",""+e);
    }
```

**I HAD CHANGED NOTHING**

**Device I am checking on Galaxy Fit**

**Giving error**

```
07-05 07:09:06.159: D/error(26994): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: have you initialized camera? please give more code

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html#tutorial_cameraapi see this article code is same to same only I had change above to.

Comment: does your log show "back Camera found"?

Comment: also does it work if you change it back to the way the article has it?

Comment: Yes I found "back Camera found

Comment: The thing is My phone don't have a front camera so I can't check that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32916/discussion-between-bumba-and-rsenapps)

Answer (score 1):

You must be using this permission for front camera

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />`

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform?answertab=votes#tab-top) question.