# Android Rear Facing Camera Take Photo without preview

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-mobile

I have followed the tutorial by **Lars Vogel** at [Tutorial Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html#tutorial_cameraapi)

While this tutorial works perfectly for the front facing camera I unfortunately cannot get the rear camera to take a photo. Its getting late and I'm probably missing something simple. My code is:

```
private int findBackFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = 0;
    // Search for the back facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found"  + info.facing);
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct permissions for the back facing camera listed in your android manifest.

Also, check out this question: [How do I open the "front camera" on the Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform?answertab=votes#tab-top)