# How to launch front facing camera (webcam)

Tags: android, eclipse, camera

I am writing an Android App using Eclipse.  As soon as the app is clicked I want the front facing camera launched so that the person see live picture of themselves through front facing camera.  I am unable to find the code for this

Comment: That should be pretty straight-forward to achieve, but what did you try and what exactly didn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform