# Android codes to automatically open camera in front facing mode?

Tags: android

I am developing a simple app to automatically capture image using front camera and self timer in a button click. I tried some of the sample but didn't work. Only for rear camera only. Your response is much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code that you tried, then explain what specific problems that you encountered when modifying that code to use a front-facing camera.

Comment: This can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform

Comment: Thanks @Satty ...much appreciated. how about with automatic self timer for 5 seconds? :-) thanks

Comment: @DanteArimbuyutan You need to read CommonsWare's suggestion. Also, you need to research things and not beg for code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mCameraId = CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) 
    setRecordingCamera(mCameraId);
```

Comment: select is as answer :-)