# How to swtich from back camera to front camera on button click?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I know i am asking question is possibly duplicate.
but i tried all things but not succeeded in any .
i have try the following things to switch camera :

```
numberOfCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
                camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BACK TO FRONT" ,
    1000).show();
                    try {
                        camera.release();
                        camera = Camera.open(camId);
                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                        camera.startPreview();
                        previewing = true;
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }else if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FRONT TO BACK" , 



     1000).show();
                        try {
                            camera.release();
                            camera = Camera.open(camId);
                            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                            camera.startPreview();
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
```

--this code is not working..it is showing toast..but not switching camera.

Comment: In your code, for each exception call e.printStackTrace(), and get the logs and post it here.

Comment: try to call `camera.stopPreview()` before `camera.release()`

Comment: @calvinify .. not working

Comment: Please add `Log.e("CameraSwitch", "failed to open camera " + camId, e)` to  `catch (RuntimeException e)` and let us see the runtime exception.

Comment: Related question: *[How to open “front camera” on android platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)*

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it on a side project. It's a [custom surface view](https://github.com/paristote/picss-android-app/blob/master/src/com/philipoy/picss/views/PicssSurfaceView.java) which defines a method for switching camera.

**Note:** as per Alex's comment, my initial answer was incorrect. I have updated the answer but I haven't tested it nor updated the file linked above.

Here's a summary of what is done:

**You need your current Camera ID in a class variable**

```
int currentCameraId;
```

**Backup the Camera.Parameters**

You need to reuse the height and width information later on.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
```

**Stop preview**

```
if (inPreview) {
  camera.stopPreview();
}
```

**Release Camera**

```
camera.release();
```

**Get the new camera ID**

```
int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
if (cameraCount == 2) {
    // simply switch between 0 and 1 if there are only 2 cameras
    currentCameraId = currentCameraId == 0 ? 1 : 0;
} else {
    Camera.CameraInfo currentCameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(currentCameraId, currentCameraInfo);
    // switch between front and back facing
    int wantedCameraFacing = currentCameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT ? Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK : Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    currentCameraId = switchCamera(cameraCount, wantedCameraFacing);
}
```

**switchCamera method (untested)**

```
int switchCamera(int cameraCount, int wantedCameraFacing) {
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    for (int camId = 0; camId < cameraCount; camId++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == wantedCameraFacing) {
            // selects the 1st camera which faces the correct way
            return camId;
        }
    }
}
```

**Open the Camera**

```
camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
```

**Init Preview with saved parameters**

```
camera.setPreviewDisplay(sHolder);
// define parameters, e.g. parameters.setPreviewSize()
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

**Start Preview**

```
camera.startPreview();
```

**Usage**

Set this custom view in your activity layout. Create a callback function for your button's `onClick` action. Then you can simply call:

```
public void switchCamera(View v) {
      preview.switchCamera();
}
```

Comment: Indeed it looks like there is no relation between `CameraInfo` and the parameter of `Camera.open()`, I guess I was just lucky. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: would you kindly fix your answer, please?

Comment: This should do it but I haven't tested.