# Open the Front camera in a surface view

Tags: java, android, camera

I am getting exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to get camera info`
at `Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId,info);`

My code is:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    int cameraId = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<Camera.getNumberOfCameras();i++){
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId,info);
        if(info.facing== Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
}
```

and manifest also have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

What thing is missing, and how can I solve that?
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open "front camera" on android platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)

Comment: Thanks @Madhur!! but I am getting Exception dear :)

Comment: Try to get cameraId in activity oncreate method and open camera in surfacechanged.

Comment: @NitinMali It didn't helped, I am getting black screen now.

Comment: Also call camera.startpreview() in surfacechanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the approach; previously I was implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback` but now I created its object.

I moved code from `SurfaceCreated` to `onResume()`

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    for(int i=0;i<Camera.getNumberOfCameras();i++){
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i,info);
        if(info.facing== Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    camera=Camera.open(cameraId);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

And the object of Callback is like:

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()

    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                    parameters);
        Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if (size!=null) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            cameraConfigured=true;
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // no-op
    }
};
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception because you initializing cameraId to -1 which is wrong.
and passing it to get Camera info

`Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId,info);`

initialize cameraId to 0 to get rid from exception.

Comment: Yes that's true. Thanks!!
But now the screen appears is Black, front camera view isn't showing.

Comment: provide your complete code to see what's goes wrong..
Also marked as correct answer

Comment: I have posted an answer, Please see and it'll be great if you can improve that.

Answer (score -1):

This Method will return the front Camera Id:

```
private int getFrontCameraId(){
            int camId = -1;
            int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            Camera.CameraInfo ci = new Camera.CameraInfo();

            for(int i = 0;i < numberOfCameras;i++){
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i,ci);
                if(ci.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                    camId = i;
                }
            }

            return camId;
        }
```

Pass this id here : `camera=Camera.open(getFrontCameraId());`