# Can't open front android built in camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2, camera2

When I run my code for opening the front camera I just see a black screen that is getting brighter to the bottom (Looks like a camera capture).

My Code:

```
public class Cam extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam);


        openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
    }
    private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread()
        {
            int cameraCount = 0;
            Camera camera = null;
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++)
            {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                        Log.e("Camera Operation", "Camera opned");
                    }
                    catch (RuntimeException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("Camera Operation", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
        }

        return camera;
    }
}
```

Any advise would be appreciated.

Note: Same screen is showing with camera2 API code.

Comment: Check this stackoverflow question for reference:- [How to open “front camera” on android platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)

Comment: Where is your onpreviewframe callback? what surface are you using to make a preview of the camera? any strange logs in the logcat?

Comment: @uelordi I don't use onpreviewframe callback or a surface.