# ZXing auto start with front camera

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to build an app that reads a QRCode from an IDCard that everyone on my company will use.

I would like to use the front camera as default when I run the app. I managed to do it with the rear camera but ideally I don't want to have to use a button to switch.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    Passageiros mPassageiro; //

    Collection<Passageiros> listaPassageiros;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this){

            @Override
            protected IViewFinder createViewFinderView(Context context) {
                return new CustomZXingScannerView(context);
            }

        };
        List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<>();

        formats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

        setContentView(mScannerView);

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }

        }
    }

...

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Daniel Kaparunakis Thx for the revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sources of ZXing library

ZXingCameraView is extending [BarcodeScannerView](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/072a087de5abe1825f648c282e041ae6f90dd45b/core/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/core/BarcodeScannerView.java), which has a private CameraWrapper which you can set with setupLayout method. CameraWrapper allows you to initialize com.android.Camera.

And how to choose necessary out of available cameras is shown in that question: [How do I open the "front camera" on the Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)

Edit: Actually there is even a [ZXing CameraUtils class](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/072a087de5abe1825f648c282e041ae6f90dd45b/core/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/core/CameraUtils.java) selecting camera on the back of device. Just change it to return id of front camera and pass that id to startCamera(frontCameraId) on your ZXingCameraView.

Comment: I am sorry man, but i am still learning. I bet you where clear, but can you explain me a litle more?

Comment: Got it. i putted mScannerView.startCamera(1); on my onResume