# Live Video Streaming in Android

Tags: video, streaming, live-streaming

I would like to stream live from the video camera of my mobile phone to my pc. Is there an API available? Applications like qik or livecast are not very useful to me, because I want something open source in order to change it...

Comment: I am sorry I didn't know how it worked. I just saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFile%28java.lang.String%29) has encoding functionality, but the current version seems file-centric, so I think you cannot stream live, unless you map a remote filesystem. If Android has WebDAV FS support, there is a good chance you can write a server-side retrieving script in something like PHP.

Comment: @Alex One of the asnwers here have a good example. Also note that you need a surface first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032912/android-does-anyone-know-how-to-capture-video